# jQuery Slide Toggle function not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble with jQuery Slide Toggle.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().children("p").Toggle(400);
    return false;
    });
    });
```

I have a bunch of posts on the page pulled from a database, and they are structured like this (pseudo HTML)

```
<div post>
    <div float-left location/timeInfo></div>
    <div float-right bandInfo><a>slideToggleLink</a></div>
    <p>theToggledElement</p>
</div>
```

When I click the link, the jQuery function is not called, but I cannot see what the problem is.

Comment: What is "pseudo HTML"?  Will a pseudo answer work?

Comment: What do you think pseudo HTML is? I didn't want to post the whole thing so I used a pseudo mark-up to give the gist of the structure of the elements.... because I believed that it was the structure which was part of the problem, whereas now we know it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery does not have a `Toggle()` method.

You mean `slideToggle()`.

Comment: jQuery does have a `.toggle()` method.  It's just not spelled `.Toggle()`.

Comment: @elclanrs, yes, the OP wants it to slide.  It does not change the fact that jQuery **has** a "toggle" method, contrary to the wording of this answer.

Comment: @Sparky672: My answer is case-sensitive.

Comment: Yes, your answer is technically correct.  However some may read it and think there's no toggle method at all.  I just made my comment as a point of clarification, more than correction.

Comment: .toggle() is actually a nicer animation. I'm keeping it. Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about jQuery "Slide Toggle" but your code is using something called `.Toggle()`, which does not exist as it is spelled.

It should be [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) or just [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) (note: the lack of capital T in the second).  However, there is no sliding/animation with `.toggle()`.

Comment: Damn. That was dumb. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).parent().parent().children("p").Toggle(400);
```

Bad for performance and `Toggle()` does not exist.
Replace with:

```
$('#post').find('p').slideToggle(400);
```

Comment: Well, you should post your not pseudo html then.

Comment: Meh. It's JavaScript... I don't really care about performance.

Comment: Ok, well, bit by bit you'll end up with such bloated code that is not even gonna run.

Comment: How do you even know that? This could be the only JavaScript/jQuery in the whole site for all you know.

Comment: Do whatever you want. First, if you're asking this question is because your knowledge of jQuery/js is not as good as you think and second, performance should be a priority in any case. I'm just showing you what I believe is the right way to do it by experience. Answers like "Meh. It's JavaScript" are no good, and it'll bite you later on.